# XSLT Filtering based on nodes and attributes

Tags: xslt

I'm new on XSLT and have a requirement to use XSLT to select values from an XML file of this form :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<deviceInstallation>
    <order>
        <orderID>296</orderID>
        <orderPosID>1</orderPosID>
        <action rvcd="2">unInstall</action>
    </order>
    <deviceInfo>
        <actionInfo rvcd="1">Software Install</actionInfo>
        <device>
            <deviceID>1436</deviceID>
        </device>
    </deviceInfo>

    <deviceInfo>
        <actionInfo rvcd="2">Software Uninstall</actionInfo>
        <device>
            <deviceID>4112</deviceID>
        </device>
    </deviceInfo>
</deviceInstallation>
```

I need to filter the elements deviceinfo based on the attribute rvcd = 2 because this is what is defined on the same attribute of child element action of the order element.

I tried to write and xslt and used a var to get the value to filter but don't know how to use it :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="'&#59;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#10;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="actionFilter" select="/deviceInstallation/order/action[]/@rvcd" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>orderID;DeviceID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        <xsl:for-each select="/deviceInstallation">
            <!--OrderID-->
            <xsl:value-of select="/deviceInstallation/order/orderID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <!--DeviceID-->
            <xsl:value-of select="/deviceInstallation/deviceInfo/device/deviceID"/> <!-- here want to filter on rvcd-->
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you post what you expect as an output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/deviceInstallation">
    <xsl:variable name="orderID" select="order/orderID" />
    <xsl:variable name="actionFilter" select="order/action/@rvcd" />
    <xsl:text>orderID;DeviceID&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="deviceInfo[actionInfo/@rvcd=$actionFilter]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$orderID" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="device/deviceID" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or perhaps a bit more elegantly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:key name="dev" match="deviceInfo" use="actionInfo/@rvcd" />

<xsl:template match="/deviceInstallation">
    <xsl:variable name="orderID" select="order/orderID" />
    <xsl:text>orderID;DeviceID&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('dev', order/action/@rvcd)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$orderID" />
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="device/deviceID" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```